# OpenCL boolean expression unwanted lazy evaluation

Tags: c, opencl, lazy-evaluation, boolean-expression

From OpenCL 2.0 specification, chapter "6.3 Operators", page 29:

> g.  The logical operators and (&&), or (||) operate on all scalar and vector built-in types. For 
>   scalar built-in types only, **and (&&) will only evaluate the right hand operand if the left hand 
>   operand compares unequal to 0**.  For scalar built-in types only, **or (||) will only evaluate the 
>   right hand operand if the left hand operand compares equal to 0**.  For built-in vector types, 
>   both operands are evaluated and the operators are applied component-wise.  If one operand is 
>   a scalar and the other is a vector, the scalar may be subject to the usual arithmetic conversion 
>   to the element type used by the vector operand. The scalar type is then widened to a vector 
>   that has the same number of components as the vector operand. The operation is done 
>   component-wise resulting in the same size vector.

This means that using expressions with logical operators will result in branching and thread divergence, which in turn results in a loss of performance on some parallel platforms. Example:

```c
int min_nonzero(int a, int b)
{
    return (a < b && a != 0)? a : b; // branch
}
```

This can be partially fixed, as:

```c
int min_nonzero(int a, int b)
{
    return select(b, a, a < b && a != 0); // branch because of &&
}
```

Where the built-in function [`select`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/select.html) will likely be implemented using arithmetics to avoid branching (e.g. as linear interpolation). But there is still the branch in `&&`. A possibly better way:

```c
int min_nonzero(int a, int b)
{
    return select(b, a, (int)(a < b) & (int)(a != 0)); // branch free
}
```

But that quickly becomes unreadable.

So my question is: **is there a better way of convincing the OpenCL compiler to abandon the lazy evaluation of the boolean expressions** (not globally but in selected cases)**?**

---

Below is my practical experimentation in this matter, not really a question anymore. Lazy evaluation is still required in some cases, such as in:

```c
if(i < N && array[i] == x) // will go OOB without lazy evaluation
```

So it is quite unlikely that the optimizer would disable it entirely or at least in all applicable cases.

I'm looking at some PTX generated by NVIDIA 320.49 driver and it will only optimize cases with no array access on the right:

```c
if(p[i] == n_end && i)
    return;
```

compiles to a single branch:

```
    setp.ne.s32     %p2, %r17, %r5; // p[i] != n_end
    setp.eq.s32     %p3, %r28, 0; // !i
    or.pred     %p4, %p2, %p3; // (p[i] != n_end || !i) = !(p[i] == n_end && i)
    @%p4 bra    BB2_3; // branch
    ret;

BB2_3:
```

Yet this:

```c
int n_increment = 1;
for(++ i; i < n_cols_B && p[i + 1] == n_end; ++ i)
    ++ n_increment;
```

compiles to:

```
    mov.u32     %r29, 1;

BB2_4:
    mov.u32     %r6, %r28;
    add.s32     %r8, %r6, 1;
    ld.param.u32    %r24, [Fill_ColsTailFlags_v0_const_param_0];
    setp.ge.u32     %p5, %r8, %r24;
    @%p5 bra    BB2_6; // branch if i < n_cols_B

    shl.b32     %r19, %r6, 2;
    ld.param.u32    %r25, [Fill_ColsTailFlags_v0_const_param_1];
    add.s32     %r20, %r19, %r25;
    ld.const.u32    %r21, [%r20+8];
    setp.eq.s32     %p6, %r21, %r5;
    @%p6 bra    BB2_7; // branch if p[i + 1] == n_end

BB2_6:
    shl.b32     %r22, %r5, 2;
    ld.param.u32    %r27, [Fill_ColsTailFlags_v0_const_param_2];
    add.s32     %r23, %r27, %r22;
    st.global.u32   [%r23], %r29;
    ret;

BB2_7:
    add.s32     %r29, %r29, 1;
    mov.u32     %r28, %r8;
    bra.uni     BB2_4;
```

Seems like it is shy of the array access as it doesn't know how to analyze correctness of the array access with respect to the condition on the left. Switching order of the conditions to `p[i + 1] == n_end && i < n_cols_B` gets rid of the branch in this case. Changing the index to a constant `i < n_cols_B && B_p[j] == n_end` (where `j = get_global_id(0)` is initialized at the beginning) does not get rid of the branch.

Comment: The casts and parentheses in your third version (and also in your second one) are unnecessary, so your objection to readability is somewhat not justified (I understand the intent, but you're basically asking for an operator which behaves like `&` with the only difference that you don't find it hard to read without a lot of parentheses, which I doubt exists).

Comment: As a note, the unintuitive precedence of the `&` operator origins from exactly that usage (before `&&` was invented in the very early days of C).

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what kind of situation are those "branches" a performance issue?

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae read up on the CUDA execution model. There the threads are executed in packs of 32 (called *warps*), which all must execute the same instruction. If they don't, then all the 32 threads need to perform both branches, with appropriate masking bits enabled, which makes it 2x slower.

Comment: @mafso you're right, I could have removed some of the parentheses. I know that there is no such operator, but maybe someone knows a good convention of writing these expressions.

Comment: I'm aware of how GPU works. My question was a polite way of telling you that your problem seems like premature optimization.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae And I believe I politely explained what the problem is. I don't think it is premature, since I'm optimizing some code to run fast on a GPU, and I'm trying to fit my instructions under the memory latency - so each clock cycle counts. I don't think anyone really bothers writing OpenCL code that is not optimized for performance in the first place - then it could have stayed on a CPU (maybe with exception of embarrassingly parallel algorithms where one can get a reasonable speedup without any effort whatsoever).